# Best way to track what users do in my iOS app with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I`m working in an app that currently track what the users is doing by adding an string to an array that is store in the users document in firebase cloud firestore.

Example of an user document:

```
...
email: user1@gmail.com
events: ['"register", "log_in", "video_one_started", "video_one_finished", "log_out", "log_in", ...]\
...
```

And so on, this list is limitless. The thing is that documents in firebase have a limit, right?
One day this will explode.

I have two questions:

1) What happens once a user reaches that limit? Is the app unusable for that user?

2) Whats the best approach to have this type of tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen Firebase's integration of Google Analytics? Documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics

Allows for "...unlimited reporting for up to 500 distinct events that you can define..."

Seems like it would be the best approach for you here.